# Webrtc: Can't find VideoRendererGui

Tags: android, webrtc

When I upgrade my webrtc version to newer version.

In newer version "VideoRendererGui" was dispeared.

My question is:

How to change this code with newer version webrtc.

```
VideoRenderer.Callbacks localRender = VideoRendererGui.create(0, 0, 25, 25, VideoRendererGui.ScalingType.SCALE_ASPECT_FILL, true);
VideoRenderer.Callbacks localRender = VideoRendererGui.update(localRender, 0, 0, 100, 100, VideoRendererGui.ScalingType.SCALE_ASPECT_FILL, false);
```

Any hints or links are fine.

Thanks.

Comment: what is version of your webRTC lib?

Comment: @sontruongit I'm using with gradle 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.20723'

Comment: WebRTC has changed API a lot in newer versions and there are many APIs has been deprecated as well. I think you should go github projects or google links to see how to use newer APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this is what you need to know

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=7158

> Remove VideoRendererGui
>
> This file is deprecated and use of it should be replaced with
> SurfaceViewRenderer instead.

Also, VideoRenderer class is removed, use -> VideoSink instead